# Why won't my list populate? IndexError: List Out of Range

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

Reading up on Stacks so I tried out this Infix to Postfix exercise (found [here](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/BasicDS/stacks.html#general-infix-to-postfix-conversion)).  You'll have to scroll a little bit to see their code.  I tried to stay as true to their original implementation as possible.

My code: http://pastebin.com/dG4Ku14n

I'm getting an error on line 18 (where I define the peek variable).  It says the list is out of range but I shouldn't have called the list yet?  Shouldn't it just be stored in the variable and the actual error should occur later in the document when I use "prec[peek]" on line 49?

I'm sure this code is more fubar than I realize.  Any help would be appreciated.  Should I start over?

Short version:

```
peek = operator_stack[len(operator_stack)-1]
for element in infix:
    if:
        #code
    else:
    while not operator_stack and prec[peek] >= prec[element]:
        output_queue.append(operator_stack.pop())
    operator_stack.append(element)
```

Expected Output:

```
A B * C + D *
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) and include it directly into the question.

Comment: please post your expected output

Comment: added expected output

Comment: @pope I think although you `tried to stay as true to their original implementation as possible.` it didn't occur that way :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you `operator_stack` list is empty therefore it returns a `IndexError` BTW if you want to find the last element of a list use and make sure to make it to `None` if its empty:

So use:

`peek = operator_stack[-1] if operator_stack else None`

instead of:

`peek = operator_stack[len(operator_stack)-1]`

Also when debugging your code it is clearly visible from the comments that these lines in:

*line 49* :`while not operator_stack and prec[peek] >= prec[element]:`

*line 59* : `while not operator_stack:`

should actually look like:

*line 49* :`while operator_stack and prec[peek] >= prec[element]:`

*line 59* : `while operator_stack:`

Finally add a if statement to check if `peek` is `None`

A short version would be

```
#line 18
peek = operator_stack[-1] if operator_stack else None
#line 49
if peek is not None:
    while operator_stack and prec[peek] >= prec[element]:

            #Append the pop'd element of the operator stack to the
            #output_queue list.
            output_queue.append(operator_stack.pop())

    #Append whatever is left (+,-,*,/) to the operator stack
    operator_stack.append(element)

    #line 59
    while operator_stack:
            #Append the last element in the stack until the stack is empty.
            output_queue.append(operator_stack.pop())
```

If you [doubt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129563/why-wont-my-list-populate-indexerror-list-out-of-range/20129672#comment30000816_20129672) what `while operator_stack:` means, see this simple example:

```
>>> a = [2,5,6]
>>> while a: # a is not empty right?
...     print 2 # so print 2
...     break # and break
2
```

Comment: Won't help because the stack is empty.

Comment: @MarkRansom just noticed that

Comment: What about `peek = (operator_stack[-1:] + [None])[0]`?

Comment: Thank you.  I will have to test this in an hour or so and if it works I'll check your answer!  I have a question though.  Does while operator_stack ... mean that it is NOT empty?  That's what I intended it to me.

Comment: @pope *just for the fact :* you ain't replacing `opStack = Stack()` with `operator_stack = []`

Comment: @pope yup `while operator_stack:` means its not empty see above I updated answer

Comment: @KDawG Oops, I meant it should be empty as in opStack.isEmpty().  Also why can't the list replace the stack?

Comment: @pope `Stack()` is a class with many instances and methods, its hard to mimic them but it is possible if you know *what they actually do* under the hood

Comment: Thanks its working now!  My output is still messed up.  It reads A B C D instead of A B * C + D *.  But I guess this is just another learning opportunity!  Thanks for the help.  Some of that I knew but would have never realized unless you pointed it out but I didn't realize variables could take if statements without the colons.  That blew my mind.  Guess I've got a lot of documentation to read.